# JQuery UI Autocomplete callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to define a callback function to an input which [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin has been applied to.

I actually want to execute something on the onchange event, but, weirdly, it is triggered before the value is set. The input has a blank value when the onchage event is triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Autocomplete has its own events that you should use.

Comment: I don't see any callback function in provided link. You should mention at least one.

Answer (score 7):

Following js1568 answer. Here it is how.

```
$('selector').autocomplete({
   .
   .
   .
   change: function (event, ui) { 
       //your code
   },
   close: function (event, ui) { 
       //your code
   }
})
```

Use the close event too, if you want your code to be triggered after the user selects a value.

Comment: What? Not only are those options not listed on the link from js1568, but they don't even work. ?? Why is this here?

Comment: How to deal with event and ui when changes occurs?