# handle multi jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have to put several autocomplete input box in the same page, just like

```
<input id=ipa ...
<input id=ipb ...
<input id=ipc ...

$(ipa).autocomplete({...source:jsonp.php...data:{type:'aaa'}...
$(ipb).autocomplete({...source:jsonp.php...data:{type:'bbb'}...
$(ipc).autocomplete({...source:jsonp.php...data:{type:'ccc'}...
```

is there any way to combine them into one ?!

Thanks,

Comment: post your html code..

Comment: As in use one source for several autocomplete boxes? or use multiple sources for one autocomplete box?

Comment: one source but with different result for target ac boxes. Because there is too much code in the page if I have 10 autocomplete boxes there, I want to make it simply. I had try to blind the input boxes id, but no sucess...

Answer (score 1):

actually if you want 3 autocomplete input boxes, then you need to 3 jquery object of autocomplete class.
so if you want to reduce duplicate code, you can create function that get the input element id and datasource (or other parametrs you need), call it 3 times and store each one into different variable.

Comment: yes, thats  what I want to do. But, where should the function put,,, Can you show me some example ?!

Comment: somethings like this, i hope useful. may be syntax has an error, but general structure could be like this: http://pastebin.com/phYYGaiD

Comment: thank you, I made the function and its work. but, it doesnt work if i want to prase the result into another div.  such as #return_div in         select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).val( ui.item.return_val );
    $( return_div ).html( ui.item.return_des );
    return false;
   },

Comment: also, is that possible to add one more function inside the autocomplete that using the selected value as a parameter to prase some other call back value to the page ?! thanks

Comment: you can extend autocomplete class, what autocomplete librarie do you use now? many of them has a callback feature, but if not, you can simple add jquery event in separate part of code, somethings like on change event get value of input and ...

Comment: i am using jquery ui. Is there any simple extend autocomplete class librarie recommend?!  sorry for lower level coder's request.

Comment: good, jquery ui autocomplete has many api and widget, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6377001/2715024) and [the document](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)