# How to retrieve the value of an input on keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achieve is to output the actual value/text so that I can save it into a variable, but the console gives me a number indicator and it keeps adding to it each time I keyup.

```
<input id="usp-custom-3" type="text">
```

```js
var country1 = $("#usp-custom-3").html();
$("#usp-custom-3").on("keyup", function() { 
    console.log(country1);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two issues with your code. Firstly you need to get the `val()` of the `input`, not it's `html()`. Secondly, you need to retrieve the value every time the event happens, so place it *within* the event handler, like this:

```js
$("#usp-custom-3").on("keyup", function() {
  var country1 = $("#usp-custom-3").val();
  console.log(country1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="usp-custom-3" type="text">
```

Comment: oh of course! Thanks a lot. Now if I might, what about if the input has jquery autocomplete, your code works and it's logic, yet if i start typing "fra.." the auto complete gives me "france", the output in console tho remains "fra.." it's like not picking up the final value in the input (sorry to have kinda of moved on with the question, just noticed it after applying your bit)

Comment: That would depend on how the autocomplete works. It's either because the value of the input isn't actually 'France' - it's just made to look like that. Alternatively the plugin has amended the value programmatically which does not raise any events. In the latter case you should be able to hook to a 'select' type event on the autocomplete library which you can use to get the chosen value. If you have issues with that I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: it's ok thanks a lot, i just looked into the documentation and also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376938/jquery-ui-autocomplete-callback